# Usage of on the way up

Tags: usage

I think **be on the way up** is the correct usage, but in the following sentence

> He wrote: “Proud to be here but this wouldn’t be my list. So many films which are my favourites can’t be below my film.. and The Dark Knight deserves to be **way up**. The number 1 film in the list I totally agree with. That’s my absolute favourite of the 21st century.

Is this used correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It is just "way up". In American informal speech and writing, "way" means "very much, by far, very, etc" - I had a meal that was way expensive; you are talking way too much; that item is way up (or down) the list.

> Definition of way (Entry 3 of 3) 1 informal
>
> a: by a long distance : to a considerable degree or extent : FAR
>   is way ahead of the class
>   sat way in the back row
>
> b: by far : MUCH
>   ate way too much
>   that's way too expensive
>
> c: VERY sense 1
>   way cool
>   way excited
>
> 2: all the way
>   pull the switch way back
>
> from way back
>   of long standing
>   friends from way back

[Way (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/way)